# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen with Jenkins and Maven

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins

I get the following exception in my Jenkins job:-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:201)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:149)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:86)
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
```

......

I run my Junit test cases in this job through Maven. As suggested by Jenkins I have a new global property `MAVEN_OPTS` with a value as high as `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`.
But still I continue to get the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen`.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks Stefan for your answer. Unfortunately adding the default log4j classloader did not solve my issue. However the link provided by you solved the issue.

I had to add the following configuration in my "maven-surefire-plugin" definition:-

```
<argLine>-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
```

This has fixed my problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem today and found that it is a problem with PowerMock and Log4j, as I instantiate the logger as a static variable in the class which I want to mock. That causes a memory leak in PermGen. The approach to use the default classloader as Stefan wrote solved that problem finally, although I had to write `@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "org.apache.logging.*", "org.apache.xerces.*" })`. I think the approach to just increase the PermSize *doesn't* solve the problem, but might be ok as this memory leaks only occur during unittests.

Answer (score 3):

PowerMock has a memory leak caused by class loading stuff: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=346

You can use the default classloader for the log4j classes:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore(value = {"org.apache.log4j.*"})
public class YourTest {
    ...
}
```